# Browse classes in Eclipse workspace

Tags: java, eclipse

I have multiple projects in my Eclipse workspace, each with its own set of Java packages and classes. I would like to browse all of the classes in one tree (as opposed to navigating into each project in the Package Explorer view). I can manually do this by copying all of the Java source code from the individual projects into one monolithic project. Is there a way to do this automatically?

Thank you.

Comment: To clarify, I want to see all classes in a package in one group. When a package's classes are spread across multiple projects, you normally have to look in each project to find the classes.

Answer (score 0):

If you open the `Navigator` view (`Window` - `Show View` - `Navigator`, you may need to click `Other...`) it will show a hierarchy of folders that contain all of the files.

Comment: This shows the files under each project. I want to browse all classes from all projects in one tree.

Answer (score 0):

Do a File search ***.java** and select scope as your **workspace** and see all the source in one place.

Answer (score 0):

Make a Java search with the following parameters:

- Tab: Java Search
- Search String: *
- Search for: Type
- Limit to: Declarations
- Search in: Sources (only check this one)
- Scope: Workspace

Then, in the search result select the 'Group by file' option if you only want to see the files as a plain list, wihtout any hierarchy. Pin that search result and you're done.

Ej:
[image: Eclipse Search Options]

Comment: This is close, but I'd like to organize the classes hierarchically (in a tree).

Comment: Do you want them grouped by package? Or by what?